# extends AdminProductsController List from cutom module

Tags: php, module, prestashop, extends

I create a custom PrestaShop 1.7 module with an admin tab name test.

This tab point to class AdminTestController which extends AdminProductsController.
It is working fine for Prestashop 1.6 but not for 1.7. I see a blank page without a products list
only controller name.

I don't want to override AdminProductsController I want to create a new link to the same list.

```
class AdminTestController extends AdminProductsController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error you receive? Enable your error debugging